# React Redux adding extra field for action cause promise to return differently

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-promise, redux-promise-middleware

I want to add a isLoading flag to my action generator and reset it at my reducer. Initially without the flag, my code works and the action looks like the following

```
export function getList() {
    const FIELD = '/comics'
    let searchUrl = ROOT_URL + FIELD + '?ts=' + TS + '&apikey=' + PUBLIC_KEY + '&hash=' + HASH;
    const request = axios.get(searchUrl)
    return {
        type: FETCH_LIST, 
        payload: request,
    }
}
```

and reducer looks like

```
const INITIAL_STATE = { all: [], id: -1, isLoading: false };

export default function (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_COMIC_LIST: 
            console.log('reducer action =', action, 'state =', state)
            return {
                ...state, 
                all: action.payload.data.data.results,
                isLoading: false
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

[image: Good result]

As you can see, the object returns fine and I can get my list via action.payload.data.data.results

Note that I am using redux promise as my middleware to handle the promise.

As soon as I changed my action to the following and re run the code I get my payload (as shown in image below) to be a Promise rather than the object that was returned

```
export function getComicList() {
    const FIELD = '/comics'
    let searchUrl = ROOT_URL + FIELD + '?ts=' + TS + '&apikey=' + PUBLIC_KEY + '&hash=' + HASH;
    const request = axios.get(searchUrl)
    return {
        type: FETCH_COMIC_LIST, 
        isLoading: true, 
        payload: request,
    }
}
```

[image: isLoading added]

Why is simply adding another variable causing this problem??

Comment: Can you tell what exact promise middleware you use?

Comment: redux-promise https://github.com/acdlite/redux-promise

Answer (score 4):

Redux Promise and Redux Promise Middleware are both compliant with [Flux Standard Action (FSA)](https://github.com/redux-utilities/flux-standard-action). Add a `meta` key to the action and assign your key/value pairs within it.

Related question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35362148/4290174

From the FSA documentation:

> The optional meta property MAY be any type of value. It is intended for any extra information that is not part of the payload.

Answer (score -1):

Try this - its how its done using redux-thunk - so I'm hoping its similar to redux-promise-middleware. Also see what is returned from:

`all: action.payload` in your reducer

```
    export function getList() {
        const FIELD = '/comics'
        let searchUrl = ROOT_URL + FIELD + '?ts=' + TS + '&apikey=' + PUBLIC_KEY + '&hash=' + HASH;

        // return a promise that the middleware should handle
        // return response or error from promise
        return axios.get(url)
          .then((response) => {
            type: FETCH_LIST,
            isLoading: true, 
            payload: response
          }).error((response) => {
            //handle error
          });
    }
```

Comment: This is not correct. To solve this question, simply use the `meta` field, as mentioned in the correct answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48371940/2476275

Comment: it would be nice if Redux gave you a warning or something of what not to put in the response, because I would have never known otherwise.

Comment: You're right, that would be a nice way to solve this problem, as I've noticed people are tripped up by it. The `meta` field isn't, however, a Redux requirement, but rather a standard that Redux middleware can opt to follow. Perhaps something for said middleware to consider.

Answer (score -1):

I think the cleanest and most react-redux way is:

```
//types:
const FETCH_LIST_START = "…";
const FETCH_LIST_SUCCESS = "…";
const FETCH_LIST_ERROR = "…";

//action
const loadList = url => dispatch => {
  dispatch({type: FETCH_LIST_START });

  fetch(url)
    .then(res => {
      if (res.status !== 200) throw new Error('load failed');
      dispatch({ 
        type: FETCH_LIST_SUCCESS,
        payload : { res } }
      })

    )
    .catch(err => dispatch({ 
      type: FETCH_LIST_ERROR, 
      payload: { error } })
    );
};

//REDUCER
case: FETCH_LIST_START:
  return Object.assign({}, state, { isLoading: true });
  break;
case: FETCH_LIST_SUCCESS:
  return Object.assign({}, state, { 
     isLoading: false, 
     data: action.payload.res
  });
  break;
case FETCH_LIST_ERROR:
  …
  break;
```

So that assumes you are using redux-thunk. The basic Idea is to make your reducer handle the state, including setting the `isLoading` thing, that way, you can update your component while the request state changes… The code above is not copy/paste ready, it is meant to transport the idea.

Comment: Few questions...1. This is using redux-thunk middleware right? 2. do you know why my original code get messed up when isLoading is added?

Comment: With in the context of the question (which uses Redux Promise Middleware), this is not correct. To solve this question, simply use the `meta` field, as mentioned in the correct answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48371940/2476275